# How can I fix this error?: Exception from Tracker recompute function: TypeError: data[a[i]] is not a function

Tags: meteor, datatables

I'm using aldeed:tabular. Here is my template:

```
<template name="contactsDatatable">
    {{> tabular table=TabularTables.Contacts class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" }}
</template>
```

Here is my table config object:

```
TabularTables = {};
TabularTables.Contacts = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "Contacts",
  collection: Contacts,
  columns: [
    {data: "firstName", title: "First"},
    {data: "lastName", title: "Last"},
  ]
})
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor.js?hash=ae8b8af…:930 TypeError: data[a[i]] is not a function
    at fetchData (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:1429)
    at aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:1445
    at Object.oCol.fnGetData (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:850)
    at _fnGetCellData (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:1262)
    at _fnCreateTr (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:1872)
    at _fnAddData (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:1187)
    at _fnAjaxUpdateDraw (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:2884)
    at aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:2729
    at callback (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:2621)
    at jQuery.fn.init.ajax (aldeed_tabular.js?hash=b303d5b…:15939)
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: The data provided isn't very concrete to debug. Are you actually using data[a[i]] anywhere in your code? Can you see where the source is?

Comment: No, I'm not using that in my code. That code is in the aldeed:tabular package.